# Typeahead: Out of focus result disappears?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, virtual-keyboard

I am building a web app  and I ran into an issue with my search results. I have typeahead working and pulling in results. When I focus into the input and type, some results appear. After I hit "done", on the iOS keyboard, to get more real estate to view the results and The results clear out.

Why is the results clearing out and how do I keep it from not doing it?

Comment: Got any code to show?